# How to differentiate error messages when login and registration form used on the same page in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel-5

I know that this question looks pretty similar to this [Login and Register form on the same page Laravel 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071161/login-and-register-form-on-the-same-page-laravel-5-6) but it's not.

I want to use the login and registration form on the same page, but the problem is with validation errors whichever form is submitted with the blank field the error message shows up on both forms?

I am able to figure out the invalid credentials message by putting the protected sendFailedLoginResponse method in LoginController like this

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'login' => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }
```

but how to differentiate the other error messages like a field is required etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use different input names in your both forms, Laravel returns the error by the name of the input, that way you should be able to make difference.

So for example, email of login form make it like:

```
<input name="login_email" ... >
```

and that of registration form:

```
<input name="registration_email" ... >
```

Then error returned from Laravel controller will have either "login_email" or "registration_email" for any error related to email like "email is required", and you will be able to differentiate.

Comment: Learner, thanks for the reply, but I know this solution I am looking for a solution without changing these default input field names.